# GraphicsMagick Convert issue in node.js AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, lambda, imagemagick

Currently trying to edit an image via an URL in a NodeJS lambda. At the moment I've installed, imageMagick, GraphicsMagick and am doing the `const gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });`, also tried `const gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: "7+"});`, no positive results.

The error states: *Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: identify "-ping" "-verbose" "imageURL" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found*

Here's my code:

```
if(event.body !== null && event.body !== "" && event.httpMethod == "POST" ){

        //Do image parsing.

        gm(postedData.imageURL).identify(function(err, value) {
            console.log(value);

            if(err) {
                console.log(err);

            }
        });


        response.statusCode = 200;
        console.log(response.parsedImageURL);
        response.body =  JSON.stringify("Image has been modified successfully. ");

    }
    else{
        response.body = JSON.stringify("Request must be a post call or empty request. ")
    }
```

Comment: What OS is this, please?

Comment: It's running on a lambda. Not on any particular server, from what AWS says, runs on Amazon Linux 2, short for Linux. Currently on a x86_64 architecture with Node.js 16.x for the runtime.

Comment: If you run v7 **ImageMagick**, the command to ping an image is `magick identify ...`. If you run v6, the command is `identify ...`. So it looks like your PHP Imagick stuff is looking for v6 `identify` but you have installed v7 which only gives you the command `magick identify`. I don't use lambdas or PHP, but my guess would be you need to install an older v6 **ImageMagick** which will provide `identify`, or a newer PHP Imagick which will expect to find `magick identify`. As I said, I don't use either so I may be wrong.